# Cannot use "let" and cannot cast in TypeScript Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, typescript

```
var inputValue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("taskInputField")).value;

let d = 4;
```

When I run this, Chrome gives the following error for inputValue:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "

And for let Visual Studio says:

> "Cannot find Symbol 'let'"

and underlines it red.

What is going on?

Comment: Are you loading the original .ts file or the compiled .js in the browser? (It should be the latter.)

Comment: Chrome says it's the .ts file

Comment: You can't load .ts files directly. You have to either load the .js output of tsc.exe, or use a "transpiler" (JavaScript library) that converts from TypeScript to JavaScript on the fly.

Comment: So Visual Studio doesn't provide any help for this?

Comment: The latest versions of Visual Studio support TypeScript natively and have a "Compile on save" feature which generates the corresponding .js file each time you save the .ts file. You can then load the .js file into the browser.

Comment: @Lukas make sure you are referencing the .js file when loading the script into the web page.

Comment: Awesome, that's been solved. Thank you! What about the "Cannot find Symbol let" issue?